# How to Avoid Deadlock condition while running jobs table and avoid restarting, Does it affect the transaction or lead to data loss?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, deadlock

How to Avoid Deadlock condition while running jobs table  and avoid restarting, Does it affect the transaction or lead to data loss ?

[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPvnX.png)

Comment: If this is not resulting from your own code then you might want to raise an issue in github

Answer (score 1):

You can't really avoid them.

It's a known issue of the `database` driver and that's why it shouldn't be used in production.

You should use the `redis` driver instead.

Here I'll quote [Taylor Otwell](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/15192#issuecomment-252663714), the creator of Laravel:

> I seriously would never use the DB driver for queues in production. It
> is no intended to be a production solution.